# Hindi fonts not appearing properly in pdf when using Dynamic reports

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, hindi, dynamic-reports

Text is having some ? characters. When generating the pdf the PDF generation succeeds but the Hindi characters are the not coming problem. we are using dynamic reports. The fonts used are Arial Unicode MS and PDF encoding is "Identity-H".

Below is the code snipett used

```
FontBuilder defaultFont = stl.font()
.setFontName("Arial Unicode MS")
.setPdfEncoding("Identity-H");

JasperPdfExporterBuilder pdfExporter =export.pdfExporter(filePath)
.setEncrypted(report.isPasswordProtected())
                            .setUserPassword(report.getPassword()).setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
concatenatedReport().concatenate(jrBuilder, reportBuilder).continuousPageNumbering().toPdf(pdfExporter);
```

Please let me know if someone can help me on this.